# retrieve specific key value from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array, since i converted the string i got back from a SOAP call to an array:

```
Array
(
    [soapenvBody] => Array
        (
            [queryRequestsResponse] => Array
                (
                    [result] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [BCRcustomId] => REQ16569
                                    [BCRexternalId] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [BCRrecordId] => a035700001CM60kAAD
                                    [BCRrequestId] => a1J5700000857EYEAY
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [BCRcustomId] => SRQ100784
                                    [BCRexternalId] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [BCRrecordId] => a033E000001PxfAQAS
                                    [BCRrequestId] => a1J3E0000000GSaUAM
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I am trying to retrieve the BCRrecordId, since I need that item to make another SOAP call. I tried the following

```
function getID($array) {
    return $array['BCRcustomId'];
}   

//

$arr = array_map('getID', $array );
print_r($arr);
```

Now i get an error back on this saying it doesnt find it.

> Undefined index: BCRcustomId in
>    index.php on line 97 
>    
>  [soapenvBody] => )Array (

My assumption is that it doenst go lower than 1 level in the array. Now i am not familair with these kinds of arrays, how would I solve this? By multiple for each loops? Or is there another way to retrieve these items

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `$array` is the whole response, you need to pass only `result` part of it:

```
$arr = array_map('getID', $array['soapenvBody']['queryRequestsResponse']['result']);
```

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I needed. I didnt know I could sort out deeper in the array map. Thanks! Accept this as awnser when I can in 3 minutes